# How to make list with chars that correspond to objects

Tags: c++

Im making a ascii game where theres lots of symbols corresponding to classes.

for example # = wallTile

Now I wanted to make the tile class so that I can read the map from textfile into 2d char vectors and create tile objects from that. 
The Tileobjects use a function in the setter like "getTileBehaviourPerSymbol(char symbol)"

Now I was about to start a switch case but there sure has to be a better way.
That function should browse some list/vector/enum/array idk where there are browsable characters corresponding to a type of class.

How is that being done in C++?

Comment: One way is to use a `std::map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea use an std::map like this for example

```
#include <map>

//Assuming each object in your game inherits from a base class
std::map<char, Object> foo.

Object getObjectBySybol(char c) {return foo[c]};
```

Hopefully that clears things up:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

Comment: except you wouldn't use `operator[]` when querying a map because it's not const-friendly. you'd use `at()`

Comment: @Cameron Bell I still dont get it eventhough a map seems to be exactly what i needed, visual studio tells me: "Type name is not allowed" when I want to declare this: `std::map<char, TileType> tileTypeMap{ {'#', TileTypeWall }};`    (TileTypeWall is derived from TileType)